# How can I measure total current used

Tags: current-measurement, multimeter

I have a circuit that includes an arduino and an electromagnet thats periodically turned on.
I can easily measure the current consumed when its turned on and when its off by wiring in my multimeter in series and observing the drain. However I want to know how I can measure the total current consumed (for example overnight). The frequency in which the electromagnet will be turned on will be somewhat random.

This is the multimeter I have https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01N3RVVJ4/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I've seen some multimeters that have the capability to measure total current passed in, by the looks of it mine doesn't have that. I did consider buying one of those USB multimeters which can do this and splicing the wires to connect it in series with my circuit but I figured surely there's a better way to measure this?

Comment: There exists logging multimeter which can measure the average current over long periods of time. They are pricey though.

Comment: "Current" is a rate of flow of charge, or combined with voltage gives you a rate of flow of energy so "Total current" is a rather meaningless concept. If the electromagnet always takes the same current, you could work out average current and/or total power by getting your arduino to record the amount of time it turns the electromagnet on for.

Comment: You cannot have what you call "Total current" since current is rate at which electrons are going through a medium.  What you should look into is the total power consumed.

Comment: I can work out the power consumed from the total current drawn. Thats fairly easy to do. What I need to know is the total current drawn from the battery over a given time. As I say I can measure it with a multimeter at the point in time. I guess I could estimate an average. The electromagnet will be on for 20ms so I suppose I could just guess how many times per hour itle be on.
I would have prefered a logger that automatically did it though as over a few days I could build a more accurate measurement.

Comment: @12Lappie:  P=E/t

Comment: @Finbarr total current isnt meaningless at all. Itle give me the number of milliamps per hour which is exactly what I need.

Comment: "Milliamps per hour" IS meaningless. It's like saying "revolutions per minute per hour"

Comment: it really isnt meaningless though is it? Because thats the value I need to know. I cant stand there for 1 hour and physically measure the current draw. If the draw was uniform for the full hour then I could just measure it with a multimeter and work it out. But as I said the the frequency that the electromagnet turning on might vary. So If I can measure how much it draws then I can work out an average over a given time. I really dont think thats so hard to understand.

Comment: The first comment answers my question really. A logging multimeter will do the trick. Pricey but I dont really care about the cost.
Since I cant do it with a standard multimeter thats the choice. Or I could use one of those USB multimeters and splice the cables. to wire it into the circuit, let it run for an hour and see how much it has drained.

Comment: Think of it like a river. Current is the rate at which water flows along the river, and it would have a given value at a given time - something like, say, 2000 litres a minute. What you are after would be the total amount of water that's flown through the river in a given space of time, such as overnight. That's not "total current", it's "volume". Or in the case of the question you're asking here, "energy".

Comment: @Finbarr or in the case of the question here, "charge". If you're going to be picky, at least be right.

Comment: @Finbar but it would tell me how many litres per hour would it not? Which is what im interested in. If I measured it over like 6 hours I can divide by 6 to get the milliamps per hour. This is so I can spec some batteries for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to handle this.

1) ... buying one of those USB multimeters which can do this and splicing the wires to connect it in series with your circuit

2) Measure the current manually with the magnet on, and again with the magnet off. Use a logger that records the time the magnet spends on. Then get the average current consumption over the period by computing the time weighted average of these two figures.

3) Use a logger that measures the current moment by moment. Read sufficiently often that the timing errors are small enough for your purposes. Integrate the readings to total charge, and then divide charge by total time to get average current.

What sort of logger? You can spend various amounts of money on standalone loggers with all sorts of fun inputs. My preference is to use an Arduino and read it from a program running on a PC. If you already use arduino, then that's a cinch. As you will probably need signal conditioning to get your current measurement into a voltage, it's a neat trick to use both high and low sensitivity amplifiers into two ADC channels, one optimised for the magnet current range, one for the controller range, and figure out which one to read at the time.

Comment: this answers my question. I already know how long the magnet stays on, its 10 milliseconds, im just not sure how frequent :) but I guess I could work out an average and from that calculate the total drawn. The arduino method sounds like a good idea I shall give that a go. Thanks